# Can someone please give an example for writing dynamic array without using ArrayList?

Tags: java, arrays

I need to be add elements dynamically in to array.Can someone please help me on this?

int[] data =new int[10]; how can i make this array for dynamic entries?

I got these code from stackoverflow itself.I think it might work..

**public class DynamicArrayOfInt

{

private int[] data;

public DynamicArrayOfInt()
{

```
data = new int[1];
```

}

public int get(int position)
{

```
if (position >= data.length)
    return 0;
else 
    return data[position];
}
```

public void put(int position, int value)
{

```
if (position >= data.length)
{
    int newSize = 2 * data.length;
    if (position >= newSize)
        newSize = 2 * position;
    int[] newData = new int[newSize];  
    System.arraycopy(data, 0, newData, 0, data.length);  
    data = newData;  
    System.out.println("Size of dynamic array increased to " + newSize);  
}
data[position] = value;
```

}
}**

//System.arraycopy(data, 0, newData, 0, data.length); can anyone explain about these passing parameter?

Comment: I tried only with fixed size of array.Thing is i'm in a learning stage..if u have code for dynamic array plz share with me

Comment: @Dkkarnavar, What is the problem of using ArrayList?

Comment: @Masud,There is no problem with ArraList .Thing is i'm trying to learn the possibility of arrays

Comment: #Jens, int[] data =new int[10];  how can i make this array for dynamic entries?

Comment: @Dkkarnavar The logic is simple. If the array is full, create a bigger array and copy the array contents to it, then add the new element. You can copy the contents with a loop, or with `System.arrayCopy`.

Comment: #Kayaman,Can u plz share a simple program with your logic.

Comment: @Dkkarnavar, you first :)

Comment: I have to agree with @Masud. ArrayList does exactly this, for you. On top of that, it has interesting utility functions and is probably optimized under the hood. Besides a learning example, there really is no reason to manually reinvent the ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

you can consider following simple logic

```
        when array size is full   
        int b[]=Arrays.copyOf(data, data.length*2);
```